# WiX CopyFile with external file doesnt execute in change mode

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In my setup i copy an external file (which path comes from an custom action) into the install directory with CopyFile. This works for an clean new installation.
But when the user chooses "change installation" on second execution of the setup and choose an different external file, the CopyFile isn't executed and the file doesnt get updated.

This is the component with CopyFile. In CFGFILE is the path to the file the users has chosen stored.

```
    <Component Id="C_CopyCfgFile" Guid="0D09480A-36E8-41C9-B887-0C6AF0B99E05">
        <Condition><![CDATA[CFGFILE <> ""]]></Condition>
        <CopyFile Id="copyCFG" DestinationDirectory="INSTALLDIR" SourceProperty="CFGFILE" DestinationName="prod_556.cfg"  />
    </Component>
```

It seems that the installer doesnt recognize the change of the CFGFILE property. What must be done to, that the file is copied every time?

Edit:
In the log file the folllowig appears at change install:

```
MSI (s) (4C:38) [08:36:30:724]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying CFGFILE property. Its current value is 'C:\Users\marco\Desktop\newconfig.cfg'. Its new value: 'C:\Users\marco\Desktop\newconfig.cfg\'.
```

That is the new file that is choosen at "change" install. The original file is never mentioned in the log

Answer (score 0):

A verbose log file will tell for sure, but the Component install state is probably detected as already present since the KeyPath of the Component is just it's Directory.

So, you'll need to manually set the parent Feature of the Component install state to be reinstalled. See the [REINSTALL Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/reinstall).

Comment: In the log file the folllowig appears at change install: `MSI (s) (4C:38) [08:36:30:724]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying CFGFILE property. Its current value is 'C:\Users\marco\Desktop\newconfig.cfg'. Its new value: 'C:\Users\marco\Desktop\newconfig.cfg\'.` That is the new file that is choosen at "change" install. The original file is never mentioned in the log.

Comment: That's the Property value change. You need to start with the Component install state.

Comment: Can you give me a hint what to search for?

Comment: Look at the section of the log file with all the Component and Feature action states.

Comment: MSI (s) (4C:38) [08:36:30:726]: Component: C_CopyCfgFile; Installed: Local;   Request: Null;   Action: Null

Comment: Yep. Just like I said.

Comment: Ok and how can i set the install state manually? Is it done with an custom action? Here is an extract of the product.wxs: `<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="$(var.ProductName) $(var.Version)" Level="1" AllowAdvertise="no" Absent="disallow" Display="expand" Description="">           
 <ComponentRef Id="C_ProgramMenuDir" />
 <ComponentRef Id="C_ReleaseNotes" />
 <ComponentRef Id="C_ReleaseNotesShortcut" />
 <ComponentRef Id="C_CopyCfgFile" />`